# Can Rails use same memcached instance for data_store and session_store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

what happen when I use one memcached instance for session_store and cache_store?

For example:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211'
config.session_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211'
```

Can full cache_store remove sessions from memcached?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you fear that cache can affect on sessions (and otherwise) you can use namespaces:

```
config.cache_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211', :namespace => 'cache'
config.session_store = :dalli_store, 'localhost:11211', :namespace => 'sessions'
```